# Get Woocommerce last order id from database using php

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce, I am trying to get the last order id using the following code:

```
<?php $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);echo $order->id;//to escape # from order id $order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number())); ?>
```

But it doesn't work as I am getting a zero value.

The purpose is to add 1 to this last order ID, to get the new usable order ID.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I voted down because SO is not a free code service, also this question is too vague to give a proper answer.

Comment: Not to mention arbitrarily adding `1` to a primary key is generally a bad Idea.  Order Id being the same thing as `posts.ID`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are **NOT** a free coding service, and your 'question' doesn't show any attempt whatsoever. Please review [**this letter**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) and update your question to at least [**showcase an attempt**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would like to get the next usable **POST ID** *(Order Id)*, to save it, for example, as new Order in database with some related data.

This is **absolutely not the way** to do it and you need to **think it different**... Now you can use one of the 3 following ways:

1. **Using the WordPress** dedicated function `wp_insert_post()` that returns the post ID (Order ID).
2. **Using the Woocommerce** dedicated function `wc_create_order()` that returns the `WC_Order` Object.

   Then from the the order object, you can get the order ID using `$order->get_id()`.
3. **Using the Woocommerce** empty `WC_Order` object instance and the `save()` method:

   ```
   // Get an empty instance of the `WC_Order` Object
   $order = new WC_Order();

   // Save the order to the database
   $order->save();

   // Get the Order ID
   $order_id = $order->get_id();
   ```

---

**Addition** - Get the last Order ID in Woocommerce:

To get and display the last order ID in woocommerce use a [`WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) in this two simple line:

```
<?php
    $last_order_id = wc_get_orders(array('limit' => 1, 'return' => 'ids')); // Get last Order ID (array)
    echo (string) reset($last_order_id); // Displaying last order ID
?>
```

Tested and works